# Angular 15 - Angular Materials with Tailwindcss - Icon Button - Icon not vertically centered

Tags: angular, angular-material, tailwind-css

[image]

Here you can see that the menu button is slightly to low.

```
  <button mat-icon-button color="primary">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your

> styles.scss

Add

> .mat-mdc-button-base {
> line-height: normal;
> }